# what is the difference between gen_server:cast to gen_server:abcast

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

When looking at `abcast` [abcast man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#abcast-2),
and `cast` [cast man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#cast-2), I couldn't understand what's the difference between those two.
Can someone clarify this to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three differences between `gen_server:cast/2` and `gen_server:abcast/2,3`:

- `gen_server:abcast/3` takes a list of target nodes specifying where `gen_server` instances registered by the specified name might be found, while `gen_server:abcast/2` sends to the list `[node() | nodes()]`, whereas `gen_server:cast/2` can address only a single `gen_server` instance.
- To identify the target server, `gen_server:abcast/2,3` takes only a name, as an atom, whereas `gen_server:cast/2` can take an atom, a pid, or for the `global` and `via` options, any Erlang term.
- `gen_server:abcast/2,3` returns `abcast`, whereas `gen_server:cast/2` returns `ok`.

The first difference is the most important, as it allows for an *asynchronous broadcast* (i.e., `abcast`) to a set of `gen_server` instances across a set of nodes.